# I am unable to dynamically render add a new partial form for the given association in ruby on rails. I am using cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    <%= form_for @poll do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @poll %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :topic %>
        <%= f.text_area :topic, rows: 3, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
       </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Options</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <%= f.fields_for :vote_options do |options_form| %>
         <%= render 'vote_option_fields', f: options_form %>
      <% end %>

     <div class="links">
       <%= link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :vote_options%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
    <% end %>
```

link_to_add_association doesn't work. It shows that the template is missing when the template is actually present.

Here is my _vote_option_field.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
</div>
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove option", f %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your `vote_option_fields` view in your question? Also, you do have an underscore in the first position of the file name?  It should be `_vote_option_fields.html.erb`

Comment: do you have `_vote_option_fields.html.erb` in current folder in which this `form` is present? if its not there than you need to provide full path of partial.

Comment: yes, I do . The _vote_option_fields.html.erb is in the current folder.

Comment: Your comment says `_vote_option_fields.html.erb` but your question says "here is my `_vote_option_field.html.erb`."  Which is it?

Comment: @tweety14 are you sure its` _vote_option_fields.html.erb` than just restart your server may be it will work.

Comment: If you add data via the rails console. Does it display?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the partial path as html_options. Something like this:

```
<div class="links">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :vote_options, partial: 'your/partial/path'%>
</div>`
```